# Why can't I use HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode inside a class?

Tags: c#, .net, static, encode

I am trying to use the following code:

```
string myString = HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode("my link & details");
```

I am getting the following error:

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property.

Why can't I use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` inside a class?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

HtmlEncode isn't a static method, and requires an instance of `HttpServerUtility` to call. Since HttpContext.Current.Server is a HttpServerUtility instance, you can instead use;

```
string myString = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode("my link & details");
```

Comment: It's the same. HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode just forwards to HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Answer (score 34):

You can use `HttpUtility` instead, which has a static method that does not depend on `HttpContext`.

```
string myString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("my link & details");
```

[More info on HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Upvoted! I had the same problem but no HttpContext to use, so this was the solution for me.

Comment: This is the better way to go, you never know when your HttpContext.Current is going to be null!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET 4.5, this utility is part of System.Net.WebUtility.

```
string myString = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(my link & details);
```